# Extract Keenio Data into google spreadsheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sendgrid, keen-io

I am currently using **[ImportJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON)** to import Sendgrid Email with data Keenio Extraction Query API URL by calling the ImportJSON function in a Google Spreadsheet cell of **Sheet DATA**.

```
=ImportJSON("https://api.keen.io/3.0/projects/"& PROJECT_KEY & "/queries/extraction?api_key=" & API_KEY & "&event_collection=" & EVT_COL & "&timezone=" & TIMEZONE & "&latest=" &  LATEST & "&property_names..........", PTDATA!$AB$1)
```

In **Sheet PTDATA**, in the last column cell i am setting a random number for ImportJSON to recalculate. The function runs on Spreadsheet open event. I have also added a custom menu to call the **ReCalcCell** custom function.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('IMPORT DATA')
  .addItem('KEENIO DATA', 'ReCalcCell')
  .addToUi();
}


function ReCalcCell(){
  var min = Math.ceil(0);
  var max = Math.floor(9999);
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("PTDATA");
  sh.getRange("$AB$1").setValue(randomNum);
}
```

**PTDATA sheet** has specific column header names for which i want to pull the data from **DATA sheet**. Towards the right of these columns, i have other calculation columns which work on these specific columns.

Since the columns in **DATA sheet** always appear in a random / shuffled order, i had to write a small custom function **GCL** which takes in a header name and returns its datarange address from **DATA sheet** as a string.

```
function GCL(header,dummy) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  var headings = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()); // get the range representing the whole sheet
  var width = headings.getWidth();
  var lrow = sheet.getLastRow();

    // search every cell in row 1 from A1 till the last column
    for (var i = 1; i <= width; i++) {
        var data = headings.getCell(1,i).getValue();
        if (data == header) {
          return ((sheet.getSheetName() + "!" + columnToLetter(i)+"2:" + columnToLetter(i) + lrow).toString()); // return the column range if we find it
           break; // exit when found
        }
    }
    return(-1); // return -1 if it doesn't exist
}

function columnToLetter(column)
{
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0)
  {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

Then i use the custom function **GCL** in each specific column to get it's datarange. Once data is populated, the **PDATA sheet** is used to create different Pivots for reporting purposes.

> =ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(GCL(A1,$AB$1)))

The problems i am facing is that though the ImportJSON data populates the **DATA sheet**:

**DATA Sheet:**
[image]

- The columns appear shuffled everytime, so my calculation columns cannot calculate as the references go away. This renders the pivots useless! To counter this issue, i had to create the **PDATA sheet** to pull in specific columns using the **custom function GCL**.
- The **custom function GCL** does not always refresh and most of the time shows **#Ref error**.

**PDATA Sheet:**
[image]

BTW, my **JSON output** from Keenio looks like this:

```
{
"result":
[
{
"sg_event_id": "92-OndRfTs6fZjNdHWzLBw",
"timestamp": 1529618395,
"url": "https://noname.com?utm_campaign=website&utm_source=sendgrid.com&utm_medium=email",
"ip": "192.168.1.1",
"event": "click",
"keen": {
"timestamp": "2018-06-21T21:59:55.000Z",
"created_at": "2018-06-21T22:00:28.532Z",
"id": "555c1f7c5asdf7000167d87b"
},
"url_offset": {
"index": 38,
"type": "text"
},
"sg_message_id": "F5mwV1rESdyKFA_2bn1IEQ.filter0042p3las1-15933-5B2A68E8-36.0",
"useragent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)",
"email": "no.name@noname.com"
}, {
"sg_event_id": "bjMlfsSfRyuXEVy8LndsYA",
"timestamp": 1529618349,
"url": "https://noname.com?utm_campaign=website&utm_source=sendgrid.com&utm_medium=email",
"ip": "192.168.1.1",
"event": "click",
"keen": {
"timestamp": "2018-06-21T21:59:09.000Z",
"created_at": "2018-06-21T21:59:39.491Z",
"id": "555c1f7c5asdf7000167d87b"
},
"url_offset": {
"index": 36,
"type": "text"
},
"sg_message_id": "F5mwV1rESdyKFA_2bn1IEQ.filter0042p3las1-15933-5B2A68E8-36.0",
"useragent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)",
"email": "no.name@noname.com"
}, {
"sg_event_id": "fru_s2s1RtueuqBMNoIoTg",
"timestamp": 1529618255,
"url": "https://noname.com?utm_campaign=website&utm_source=sendgrid.com&utm_medium=email",
"ip": "192.168.1.1",
"event": "click",
"keen": {
"timestamp": "2018-06-21T21:57:35.000Z",
"created_at": "2018-06-21T21:58:20.374Z",
"id": "555c1f7c5asdf7000167d87b"
},
"url_offset": {
"index": 29,
"type": "text"
},
"sg_message_id": "F5mwV1rESdyKFA_2bn1IEQ.filter0042p3las1-15933-5B2A68E8-36.0",
"useragent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)",
"email": "no.name@noname.com"
}
]
}
```

My questions are:

- Is there a way to parse the JSON result without use of ImportJSON, which has to be entered as a custom function in a cell that also depends on recalculation? ImportJSON sometimes doesn't work properly.
- How can this code be refactored or optimized so that it can always return data to PDATA sheet columns?
- Is there a better way of accomplishing what i want without resorting to custom functions like GCL in the PDATA Sheet or ImportJSON in DATA sheet?

Comment: If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry. It seems that Q1 and Q3 in your questions are the same. If there are the differences, could you please tell me? You can parse the JSON object using [``JSON.parse()``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). About ``it can always return data to PDATA sheet columns``, what does "always" mean? Do you want to update the data using a time-driven trigger? Can you provide a sample spreadsheet? I think that it will help users think of your solution. Of course, please remove your private information.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, the Keenio URL automatically refreshes itself every few hours. Sometimes, due to this refresh, ImportJSON doesn't import the data resulting in errors. I dont want a time-driven trigger, but a menu selection that will pull the data whenever i want. Let me create a sample sheet for the returned Keenio data and share the link with you.

Comment: @Tanaike i have updated my post with images for the 2 sheets that shows how data looks. Will this help? If not, i will try to create a sample spreadsheet and share immediately. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. From the added images, I think that the JSON object can be retrieved from the API using Google Apps Script, and the script can be run from the menu. About the column title, I cannot see all of them from the images. So if you provide a sample spreadsheet, I think that I can modify your script as a version which uses class UrlFetchApp. Of course, please remove your personal information for the spreadsheet.

Comment: Sure @Tanaike. I shared the JSON which has all the relevant columns. Still i will create a spreadsheet and share it with you now.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1geZHbZ4udym-zBfKDhOGUyACevXcpf_4FAFRnfmcFaA/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample sheet. Can I ask you about what you want? You want to put the parsed data (JSON object) from API to the sheet of "DATA" form the menu. Is my understanding correct? I would like to confirm your issue before I post the script.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, that's true.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sample script? This script parses the values retrieved from API using UrlFetchApp and put them to the sheet "DATA". You can run this at the menu of spreadsheet. Before you run this, please put the endpoint.

#### Sample script :

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('IMPORT DATA')
  .addItem('KEENIO DATA', 'ReCalcCell')
  .addItem('main', 'main')
  .addToUi();
}

function main() {
  var url = "###"; // Please put the endpoint with your token.

  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(); // Modified
  var values = JSON.parse(res);
  var putData = values.result.map(function(e) {return [e.useragent, e.sg_event_id, e.timestamp, e.ip, e.url, e.event, e.keen.timestamp, e.keen.created_at, e.keen.id, e.url_offset.index, e.url_offset.type, e.sg_message_id, e.email]});
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, putData.length, putData[0].length).setValues(putData);
}
```

#### Note :

- When you use this, please put the endpoint including your token to `url`.
- I confirmed this script using the JSON object in your question. So if the structure of the object is changed, it is required to also modify the script. Please be careful this.

#### Reference :

- [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)

If I misunderstand about your issue, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Edit 1 :

#### Pattern 1 :

```
var putData = values.result.map(function(e) {return [e.useragent, e.sg_event_id, e.timestamp, e.ip, e.url, e.event, e.keen.timestamp, e.keen.created_at, e.keen.id, JSON.parse(e["url_offset"]).index, JSON.parse(e["url_offset"]).type, e.sg_message_id, e.email]});
```

#### Pattern 2 :

```
var putData = values.result.map(function(e) {return [e.useragent, e.sg_event_id, e.timestamp, e.ip, e.url, e.event, e.keen.timestamp, e.keen.created_at, e.keen.id, e["url_offset"].index, e["url_offset"].type, e.sg_message_id, e.email]});
```

### Edit 2 :

Could you please run this script and provide the values of the created file? Of course, please remove the personal information. But please don't modify the structure of the object. If you cannot do it, I would like to think of other ways.

```
var url = "###"; // Please put the endpoint with your token.

var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", res, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
```

### Edit 3 :

Please copy and paste this script in your script editor, run myFunction(). Then, please show the values of file. When you run this function, please confirm whether there are NOT the same function name in your project.

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "###"; // Please put the endpoint with your token.
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", res, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
}
```

### Edit 4 :

Please copy and paste this script in your script editor, run myFunction2(). Then, please show the results. When you run this function, please confirm whether there are NOT the same function name in your project.

Please confirm whether the keys and values of `keen` and `url_offset` are retrieved.

```
function myFunction2() {
  var url = "###";
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var values = JSON.parse(res);
  for (var key in values.result[0]) {
    Logger.log("key: %s, value: %s", key, values.result[0][key])
    if (typeof values.result[0][key] == "object") {
      for (var dkey in values.result[0][key]) {
        Logger.log("key: %s, dkey: %s, value: %s", key, dkey, values.result[0][key][dkey])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Edit 5 :

Please copy and paste this script in your script editor, run myFunction3(). Then, please show the results. When you run this function, please confirm whether there are NOT the same function name in your project.

```
function myFunction3() {
  var url = "###"; // Please set this.
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var values = JSON.parse(res);
  var obj = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.result.length; i++) {
    var temp = {};
    var v = values.result[i];
    for (var key in v) {
      temp[key.replace(/_/g, "")] = v[key];
      if (typeof v[key] == "object") {
        for (var dkey in v[key]) {
          temp[key.replace(/_/g, "") + dkey.replace(/_/g, "")] = v[key][dkey];
        }
      }
    }
    obj.push(temp);
  }
  var putData = obj.map(function(e) {return [e.useragent, e.sgeventid, e.timestamp, e.ip, e.url, e.event, e.keentimestamp, e.keencreatedat, e.keenid, e.urloffsetindex, e.urloffsettype, e.sgmessageid, e.email]});
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, putData.length, putData[0].length).setValues(putData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you are doing here, it might be much easier to design your spreadsheet in an "append-only" format with a Zapier integration.

Zapier is able to handle SendGrid events directly, and append those events to your spreadsheet, if that is what you want.

And then you can have your "calculation columns" on a separate Sheet in the spreadsheet.

Just an idea.